# Batch resize images using Photoshop's Image Processor

Tags: image, batch-processing, photoshop, image-resizing, photoshop-script

I am trying to batch resize several hundreds of images in Photoshop but I encounter a strange problem: The smaller images have a larger file size.

I am using File -> Scripts -> Image Processor with quality setting set to 8.

For  example one original file was 300x300 and 5,41 kb and the new resized image is 200x200 pixels and 17.9 kb!

How is this possible? is it related to the amount of Pixels per Inch? Resolution? The color blend palette and the number of colors used? Or something else entirely? I don't know much about these subjects so please try to help me with a constructive answer.

What is the best way to make sure they are actually smaller in file size also? (I am optimizing a websites page speed)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What format are you saving to - PNG, JPEG, GIF?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the file size of a picture with a lower resolution is bigger than it's comparison an ICC profile is embedded. Most websites (developer) ignore color management to achieve smaller file size. To find the optimal file format, you should use "Export for web" to get a preview.